# Logistic regression relationship identification

Tags: regression, logistic

Is logistic regression a correct way to identify the relationship between `lead source` (an independent variable), demographics (e.g., `gender`, `income`, etc., independent variables) and `lead outcome` (yes or no, my dependent variable)?

More details:

The values taken by `lead source` are categorical i.e. `campaign`, `referral`, `cold calling`, etc. and the demographic variables are `gender` i.e. `Male` or `Female` and `income` which is ordinal e.g. `2000`, `5000`, etc. The measurements are the outcomes of a lead management application which captures basic details about leads and also the status or outcome of the lead. I am planning to design a predictive logistic regression model which could tell on the basis of lead source and demographics, what the possible outcome (yes/no) of that lead could be.

Comment: Can you amplify your question (by editing it: the edit link is in the lower left), by describing: (1) the *numerical values* taken by 'lead source' and your demographic variables; (2) the *study design* that produced these measurements; and (3) the *causal model* informing your hypotheses?

Comment: While those are more details, they don't come close to getting at (1), (2) and (3) in my previous comment.